# Can one hide accounts in Personal Capital?

Tags: personal-capital

Mint.com and PersonalCapital.com are two sites that aggregate one's US bank accounts. On Mint.com, one may hide accounts, i.e. the accounts won't count toward the total net worth, by going to Settings -> Hide accounts. Does PersonalCapital.com have a similar feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, one cannot hide accounts in Personal Capital. Personal Capital does not have this feature natively, unlike Mint.com.